# How to show a user control in the main form panel when using only a user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

@Mark ,Yes Sir I create an event in the usercontrol.
Here is my code:

**USERCONTROL**

```
namespace Purchase_Order
{
    public partial class Static : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler ClassificationClicked;
        public Static()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClassification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClassificationClicked(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**MAINFORM**

```
public partial class formMain : Form
{

    public formMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Static.ClassificationClicked += new EventHandler(Static_ClassificationClicked); 
    }

    private void formMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Static control = new Static();
        panelSide.Controls.Clear();
        panelSide.Controls.Add(control);   
    }

    void  Static_ClassificationClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classification control = new classification();
        panelMain.Controls.Clear();
        panelMain.Controls.Add(control);
    }

}
```

And here is the error -> Static.ClassificationClicked += new EventHandler(Static_ClassificationClicked);

Comment: Did you create an event in the usercontrol ? Take another look at the usercontrol example in my answer

Comment: @Mark ,Yes Sir I create an event in the usercontrol.
Here is my code:

>namespace Purchase_Order
{
    public partial class Static : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler ClassificationClicked;
        public Static()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClassification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClassificationClicked(sender, e);
        }
    }
}

Comment: What is the namespace of your mainform,  I do not see anytbing that looks wrong. Try compiling your UserControl first before trying to add the eventhandler, then see if the event is present.

Comment: @Mark, the namespace of my mainform is Purchase_Order. I tried what you have said I commented the line -> Static.ClassificationClicked += new EventHandler(Static_ClassificationClicked); but it returned an error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) after I clicked the button classification(btnClassification). Why is that so?

Comment: Add `control.ClassificationClicked += new EventHandler(Static_ClassificationClicked);` in your FormMain_Load EventHandler.

Comment: Please look at my updated answer, you are creating your control with Method level scope, it is not visible in your forms constructor, I modified it so the UserControls have class level scope and the static usercontrol is created in your form's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `btnClassification_Click` is a method on your `static` user control, that is located on an instance of your `formMain`.

Your problem is that in your `btnClassification_Click` method, you create a new instance of the `formMain` class instead of accessing the instance that your `static` user control is on.  It looks like you've already publicly exposed `mainPanel` in the `formMain` class, so you just need to find the right instance of the `formMain` class to add your user control to.  To do that, put this method in your `static` user control:

```
private Form GetParentForm()
{
    Control current = this.Parent;
    while (current != null)
    {
        Form form = current as Form;
        if (form != null)
        {
            return form;
        }

        current = current.Parent;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then call this method from your event handler:

```
private void btnClassification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classification control = new classification();
    formMain main = (formMain)this.GetParentForm();
    main.panelMain.Controls.Clear();
    main.panelMain.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Comment: Yes btnClassification_Click is a method but it is located on the user control 'static'.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create an Event on your UserControl and subscribe to it in your MainForm. In my opinion it is not proper for the UserControl to have knowledge of the Parent Form. Something like this:

**Add event to your UserControl:**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ClassificationClicked;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClassification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassificationClicked(sender, e);
    }
}
```

**Subscribe to it in your MainForm**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl11.ClassificationClicked += new EventHandler(userControl11_ClassificationClicked);
    }

    void userControl11_ClassificationClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classification control = new classification();
        panelMain.Controls.Clear();
        panelMain.Controls.Add(control);

    }
}
```

---

Edit based on Comment Stream. I would also make sure that your Usercontrols have unique names not just control, that way you can differentiate between them.

```
public partial class formMain : Form
{
    Static staticControl;
    Classification classificationControl;

    public formMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        staticControl= new Static();
        panelSide.Controls.Clear();
        panelSide.Controls.Add(staticControl);
        staticControl.ClassificationClicked += new EventHandler(Static_ClassificationClicked); 
    }

    void  Static_ClassificationClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classificationControl = new classification();
        panelMain.Controls.Clear();
        panelMain.Controls.Add(classificationControl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Hall's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16205612/80274) answer is the best, however I wanted to add that you should not raise the event directly but first check that there are subscribers then raise the event. This will stop a null reference exception if no one has subscribed to the event yet.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ClassificationClicked;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClassification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseClassifactionClicked();
    }

    private RaiseClassifactionClicked()
    {
        var tmp = ClassificationClicked; //This is added for thread safty
        if(tmp != null) //check to see if there are subscribers, if there are tmp will not be null
           tmp(this, EventArgs.Empty); //You don't need to pass along the sender and e, make your own here.
    }
}
```

For more on the thread safty trick read [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx)